# OleDBException was unhandled by user code. Error Message: OverFlow

Tags: c#, binary, overflow, oledbconnection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEmDB.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIDiS.png)I try to insert data to my MS Access Database. My table's name SignUp.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNameSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSurnameSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPhoneSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@mail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMailSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddressSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserNameSignUp.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPasswordSignUp.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cnn.Close();
cnn = null;
```

I tried to `(OleDBType.Binary).Value = Convert.ToByte(txtPhoneSignUp.Text);` for Phone's textbox but then it said "Too large" or "Too small".

> sorgu = "INSERT INTO SignUp
>   ([Name],[Surname],[Phone],[Mail],[Address],[UserName],[Password])
>   values (@name,@surname,@phone,@mail,@address,@username,@password);";
>               cmd = new OleDbCommand(sorgu, cnn);
>
> ```
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtNameSignUp.Text);
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtSurnameSignUp.Text);
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Convert.ToDouble(txtPhoneSignUp.Text));
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", txtMailSignUp.Text);
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddressSignUp.Text);
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserNameSignUp.Text);
>         //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtPasswordSignUp.Text);
>
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtNameSignUp.Text;
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@surname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSurnameSignUp.Text;
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = 
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@mail", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtMailSignUp.Text;
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtAddressSignUp.Text;
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUserNameSignUp.Text;
>         cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPasswordSignUp.Text;
>
>             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>             cnn.Close();
>             cnn = null;
> ```

Comment: I am going to guess that you have the phone number defined as a numeric in the db?  The query would be nice to see.

Comment: i tried numeric and text but both of didn't work

Comment: Please show the definition of your table (and ideally what dbms you are using). If your phone column is numeric, you cannot add the parameter as `VarChar`. But most phone numbers will probably be "too big" for a numeric column as they have too many digits.

Comment: The important thing here is *probably* the query (command `.CommandText`) - and ideally any column definitions. Can we see those bits? Also: **never never store passwords**

Comment: Storing PWs as plaintext is a very bad idea - they should be hashed and salted

Comment: @Plutonix wouldn't it be a beautiful relief if the overflow is actually the password parameter, because the query wants to store a hash, not a string? I'm not overly optimistic...

Comment: `Convert.ToByte(txtPhoneSignUp.Text);` would not work in most cases, unless the phone number is in a *very* small range; can we please see the query?

Comment: yes of course. i'm editing

Comment: and i'm changing the password thing thank you.

Answer (score 0):

for OleDBType.Binary you need a byte[], so change your code to

Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPhoneSignUp.Text)

Comment: i can't write 'Encoding'. has it diffrent namespace or?

Comment: it works but there is new exception. it says Failed to convert parameter value from a Byte[] to a String. when i tried to oledbtype.binary it gives same error.

Comment: i tried to

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", OleDbType.Binary).Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtPhoneSignUp.Text);

it gived:

Data type mismatch in criteria expression.